# the opposite function for the done function in ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send a form via `Ajax`, with `jQuery`.

On submitting the form, a loading image will be shown on the data transferring.

In pure `JS` I used this code :

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    var formData = new FormData(myForm);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            loading.style = "visibility:hidden;";
            alert('Authentification réussi.\n' + xhr.responseText );
        }else{
            loading.style = "visibility:visible;";
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "authentification.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(formData);
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

And this is what I tried using `jQuery` :

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type        : $('#myForm').attr('method'),
    url         : $('#myForm').attr('action'),
    data        : $('#myForm').serialize(),
    dataType    : 'html'
});
    

$(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(event){
        jqxhr.done(function(data){
            $('#loading').hide();
            alert(data);
        });
        //Here the other method
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is I don't know what it the function that will be executed on sending data, in pure `JS` I just used the else statement for : `xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200`.

So, what is the function which is responsible for that ?

## Edit :

The solution was to use the attribute `beforeSend` as the following :

```
jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type        : $(this).attr('method'),
    url         : $(this).attr('action'),
    data        : $(this).serialize(),
    dataType    : 'html',
    beforeSend  : function(){
                        $('#loading').show();
                    },
        complete    : function(){
                            $('#loading').hide();
                    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sent the ajax request within the submit handler... when you say `$.ajax(..)` the ajax request is sent and the since you have placed the code in global context `this` refers to the window object.

```
var jqxhr;
$(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
        jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            alert(data);
        }).always(function () {
            jqxhr = undefined;
        });
        //Here the other method
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: for `$(this)` I just forgot to modify it, I used `$('#myForm') `insted. And I did used `$.ajax(..)` inside the submit handler, but I needed to abort the `Ajax` query on another handler, so I needed to declare it globally.

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU in that case just declare the variable globally and before calling abort check whether the value is not undefined like `if(jqxhr != undefined){jqxhr.abort()}` (see the update)

Comment: Why is `jqxhr` global?

Comment: @Bergi from OP's comment to the original answer `but I needed to abort the Ajax query on another handler, so I needed to declare it globally` though I would not recommend creating it as a global variable instead could suggest to use it as a closure variable

Comment: @ArunPJohny, thanks that was helpful, but the original question was that I need the opposite function for `done()` function, because nor `fail()` nor `always()` can do that.

Comment: The literal opposite of done is start so truly what are you trying to say as your English is poor.  jQuery clearly states all the available function callbacks that are allowed. Now if you want start create your own sort of jquery plugin I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It might work. You can use `beforeSend` to show your loading image and hide it on `done`.